# QuickBooks Web Connector Remote Debugging

Tags: quickbooks

I have a web service located at www.mysite.com/qbwebservice.asmx using the QBXML SDK. If I have the code for QBWebService.asmx on my machine, can I attach a process to QBWEBConnector.exe and do remote debugging?

I have tried, however my breakpoint is never hit. Should I attach to another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QBWebService.asmx` code is not executing directly in `QBWEBConnector.exe`, so it won't do any good debugging that. The `QBWebService.asmx` code is executing on the web server, so you need to debug it there.